# How to extract a big list of characters from xml file in Java

Tags: java, xml, search, xpath, extract

I have a big xml file and I do not wish to parse it, I just want to store every single character between `<information>...</information>`, which are tags inside the xml file.

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you care whether entities like `&amp;` show up as one character or 5? Do you care whether there are other tags between the ones that you specified? If the answer to either of these questions is "yes" then you want to use a parser. Otherwise read the file into a string and search for the tags.

Comment: i used a string buffer to load the xml file into and it was only able to load half of the xml file... I thought string buffers were suppose to be big

Comment: If you mean what you're saying, you can simply use a regular expression.

Comment: do you mean i can use a regular expression on the xml file before storing it into a StringBuffer?

Answer (score 2):

If the problem is that the data you're trying to extract will fit in memory, but the entire XML file won't, then use a streaming parser such as [XPP](http://www.extreme.indiana.edu/xgws/xsoap/xpp/).

Answer (score 1):

You can't accurately find the characters in the `<information>` element without parsing the file. You could do something that works 99% of the time, but it would break when someone does something you didn't expect, like putting whitespace in the start tag, or having a commented-out `<information>` element, or putting part of the `<information>` element in an external entity.

Bite the bullet. If it's XML, you need an XML parser to read it.

Comment: I do not want to parse it. I jut want everything between 2 tags. Parsing it will lose a lot of the data that I need. Can't I just say get this xml file, look for <data> and GET everything from there to </data> ?

Comment: It's perfectly possible in theory, but I don't know of an XML parser that offers access to the unparsed data in this way. Perhaps that suggests it's an unusual requirement, perhaps that means you should look at alternative solutions to your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to explain why you don't want to parse it as that would help in suggesting other solutions.

That being said, if you can construct an XPath for that node, you can always get that information with XPath. See [this tutorial](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-javaxpathapi/index.html).

**UPDATE**

Given the new information, this isn't the solution you want. If you want to treat the xml as a string, reading it into a StringBuilder (the faster, thread-unsafe version of StringBuffer) is your best bet. If you're having trouble using StringBuffer, please post the code you tried and the error messages. It's max size is `java.lang.Integer.MAX_VALUE` which is 2147483647.

Comment: I do not want to parse it because I want to keep every single character e.g like tags <> and attributes..etc I thought of Xpath but ive never used it

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you do not want to use a parser and you are just interested in extracting all characters between two tags, I'd rather suggest you to extract the xml content as string, and use a simple regular expression match to extract the portion between the two tags.